# Change footer and header background color for style simple in powerdot

Tags: color, backgrounds, presentations, powerdot

I am using the style *simple* for creating slides with powerdot:

```
\documentclass[style=simple]{powerdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{First slide}
  Hello world!
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

While the style is otherwise good, I would like to use different background color than white for the header and the footer (match the color to my university's logo). How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[style=simple]{powerdot}

\colorlet{myColor}{red!20}%%%% your background color

\pddefinetemplate{basic}{
  titlepos={.05\slidewidth,.93\slideheight},
  titlewidth=.9\slidewidth,textheight=.66\slideheight,
  titlefont=\large\bfseries\raggedright,
  clockpos={.99\slidewidth,\slideheight},
  lfpos={.03\slidewidth,.04\slideheight},
  cfpos={.5\slidewidth,.04\slideheight},
  rfpos={.97\slidewidth,.04\slideheight},
  tocslidesep=.6ex,textheight=.68\slideheight,
  ifsetup=portrait,
    textpos={.05\slidewidth,.83\slideheight},
    textwidth=.9\slidewidth,
    tocsecsep=.6ex,
    stochook=tr,stocpos={.48\slidewidth,.09\slideheight},
    stocfont=\tiny\raggedleft,
    ntocpos={.52\slidewidth,.09\slideheight},
  ifsetup=landscape,
    textpos={.2\slidewidth,.83\slideheight},
    textwidth=.75\slidewidth
}{%
  \psframe*[linecolor=myColor](0,0)(\slidewidth,.1\slideheight)%
  \psframe*[linecolor=myColor](0,.9\slideheight)(\slidewidth,\slideheight)%
  \psline[linewidth=.8pt](0,.9\slideheight)(\slidewidth,.9\slideheight)%
  \psline[linewidth=.8pt](0,.1\slideheight)(\slidewidth,.1\slideheight)%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{First slide}
  Hello world!
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

[image]